# C - Using structures in multiple functions

Tags: c, data-structures

I have been checking Google for an hour. I have tried using typdef but I get the same results. I am having a bit of confusion in regard to structure scopes. I'm sure it's just something silly that I'm missing.

Example, prints 0:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct info
{
    int i;
};
struct info testinfo;

int test()
{

    testinfo.i = 5;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d", testinfo.i);
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Um also your example makes no sense. You never call the function test and you try to print an uninitialized string.

Comment: -1: No actual question. The sample code does not show anything

Comment: @John - I recommend that you get/read a book on C. Pay attention to local variables, scope and calling procedures.

Comment: Now you forgot to call test() in main(). And main should `return 0;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both struct info have block scope since you declare them as local variables.
They are thus different objects.
Declare only one at file scope (outside any function).

(Code in question has been edited and this answer refers to the initial bug).

Answer (score 2):

You will either need to pass the variable `testinfo` to the function `test()` or have `test()` return an `info` struct

Here is the first option:

```
int test(struct info * ti) {
  ti->buf = "test";
}
int main() {
  struct info testinfo;
  test(&testinfo);
  printf("%s", testinfo.buf);
}
```

*Note*: the `*` denotes a pointer to the structure, as otherwise you would copy the structure and any modifications to it would onlly occur in the copy (so `main`'s version would not change)

Answer (score 2):

This is unrelated to struct - you would see the same behavior with any type. What's going on is that each `testinfo` is in a different scope and namespace.

Also, you're never calling your function.

You could either make `testinfo` global, or you could pass it by pointer which is a better idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct info
{
    char* buf;
};

int test(struct info* testinfo)
{
    testinfo->buf = "test"; // it's a bad idea to have a char* to a literal
                            // you should probably allocate new storage
}

int main()
{
    struct info testinfo;
    test(&testinfo);
    printf("%s", testinfo.buf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

John, with the updated question you need to call `test` before the `printf`.

i.e.

```
int main()
{
  test();
  printf("%d", testinfo.i);
  return(0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you do

```
printf("%s", testinfo.buf);
```

testinfo.buf is not allocated! Try

```
struct info testinfo;
testinfo.buf = (char *) malloc(123);
```

<EDIT>

```
strcpy(testinfo.buf, "hello world!");
```

</EDIT>

```
printf("%s", testinfo.buf);
```

to get buffer allocated.

Comment: You also need to put some null terminated string of characters into the allocated memory for it to work.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do a

```
testinfo.buf = "test"
```

1. You have to assign space for the string, buf is just a character pointer.

`struct info
{
    char buf[10];   /*10 is the space for buf*/
};`

Also you should use `strcpy(dest,source)` when assigning strings.
And also you're not calling test.
Sort these two things out, you'll get the output.

Comment: @SleepingDragon - `testinfo.buf = "test"` is valid.

Comment: @Ed Heal But its not advised, strcpy is a better way. I didn't say "you must", I said "you should". :)

Comment: @SleepingDragon - Actually you said (and I quote from above) 'You can't do a'. You can do it. It depends on what you are going to get up to with the string. It is perfectly valid.

Comment: @SleepingDragon - Who says it is not advised? Why is it not advised?

Comment: @Ed Heal: Sorry I was wrong. I overlooked that testinfo.buf was a pointer. Apologies and thanks for pointing it out. :)